# Crackling noise and skipping audio through audio jack on left channel on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

Sorry if there is an easy fix, but I'm new to Linux and I've already tried everything I could find on the internet. The audio output of the headphone jack has a weird crackling noise, which is somehow only present on the left channel of the headphones. Also, the sound skips or echoes from time to time.
I'm dual-booting Ubuntu with Windows, and on Windows the audio jack works perfectly fine. The headphones aren't the problem either, since they work on Windows and with my smartphone as well.

**What I've tried so far**

Added the following lines seperately to the alsa-base.conf

```
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

and

```
options snd-hda-intel vid=8086 pid=8ca0 snoop=0
```

Disabled loopback and auto-mute in alsamixer

**System information**

```
Product Name: HP Pavilion x360 Convertible

lspci -nnk | grep -i audio -A2

00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [8086:9d70] (rev 21)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio [103c:81a7]
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl

cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                     HDA Intel PCH at 0xb1528000 irq 281
```

**EDIT**: I found a bug report which seems to be describing exactly the problem I'm having as well. [Crackling and popping sound when using headphones | bugs.launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1648183). Does anyone have an idea on how to temporarily fix it until it is clear when it will be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem on my HP Laptop. The following two commands solved this issue for me (requires the installation of `alsa-tools` and sudo for the commands):

```
hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 SET_COEF_INDEX 0x67
hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 SET_PROC_COEF 0x3000
```

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1648183/comments/17

The commands have to be run after every startup, therefore these two commands can be put in a sh script and run after reboot with a cronjob.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I did as well after searching for almost half a year. So weird that this bug still hasn't been fixed because it seems that it affect almost everyone with the ALC295 codec